# Chamar Método em Routes no AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Tenho um controller chamado ProdutoController no AngularJS, esse controller deveria ter dois métodos, um para listar todos os produtos quando eu passar uma URL e outro método para trazer os detalhes do produto quando for outra URL.

Exemplo:

```
/produto/:codDepartamento - Rota para listar os departamentos

/produto/ficha/:codProduto - Rota para exibir os detalhes do produto
```

Como seria feito para chamar um método a partir dessas rotas?

Comment: Eu aconselharia usar dois controllers. Mas, caso queira usar um só, dê uma olhada na documentação do `$location`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

1. Criar um segundo controller, específico para o caso de detalhes do produto

   ```
   angular.module('myApp', ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
       .when('/produto/:codDepartamento', {
         templateUrl: 'path/to/lista.html',
         controller: 'ProdutoListaController'
        })
       .when('/produto/ficha/:codProduto', {
         templateUrl: 'path/to/detalhes.html',
         controller: 'ProdutoDetalhesController'
       });
    }])
   .controller('ProdutoListaController', ['$scope', '$routeParam',
      function($scope, $routeParam) {
        /* $routeParams.codDepartamento possui o código do dpto */

        /* ... */
      }
   ])
   .controller('ProdutoDetalhesController', ['$scope', '$routeParam',
      function($scope, $routeParam) {
        /* $routeParams.codProduto possui o código do produto */

        /* ... */
      }
   ]);
   ```
2. Criar uma rota que aceite argumentos opcionais (possível desde a versão 1.2.0 do AngularJS):

   ```
   angular.module('myApp', ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
       // Note o sinal de interrogação no codProduto
       .when('/produto/:codDpto/:codProduto?', {
         templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
         controller: 'ProdutoController'
        });
    }])
   .controller('ProdutoController', ['$scope', '$routeParam', '$location',
      function($scope, $routeParam, $location) {
        if ($routeParams.codDpto === "ficha")
            if ($routeParams.hasOwnProperty("codProduto") &&
                $routeParams.codProduto) {
                // Buscar lista de produtos
             }
        } else {
             // Busca Dpto
        }
      }
   ]);
   ```
3. Usar o `$location.path()` pra saber qual a rota que está:

   ```
   angular.module('myApp', ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
       .when('/produto/:codDpto', {
         templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
         controller: 'ProdutoController'
        })
       .when('/produto/ficha/:codProduto', {
         templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
         controller: 'ProdutoController'
        });
    }])
   .controller('ProdutoController', ['$scope', '$routeParam', '$location',
      function($scope, $routeParam, $location) {
        if (/^produto\/ficha/.test($location.path())) {
            // Busca Produto. Código no $routeParams.codProduto
        } else {
            // Busca Dpto
        }
      }
   ]);
   ```

Considero a primeira alternativa a mais "correta".

Comment: Resposta bem completa, parabéns. Mas vale lembrar que para o Angular 1.2.x é necessário referenciar o o modulo de rotas:
`var app= angular.module('app',['ngRoute'])`